# How to access ng-Quill instance from controller to change toolbar in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rich-text-editor, quill

I need to change the toolbar for quill.Js using angular, I tried to use `<ng-quill-toolbar></ng-quill-toolbar>` however it is not working as expected and on multiple editor its causing error, Is there a way where it can be changed using the options as given in quill.Js document using angular

https://quilljs.com/docs/configuration/

**Module-Config**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app')
        .config(['ngQuillConfigProvider', function (ngQuillConfigProvider) {
            ngQuillConfigProvider.set();
        }]);
})();
```

**Controller**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('Ctrl', Ctrl);
    function Ctrl($document) {
        var doc = $document[0];

        var container = doc.getElementsByClassName('editor');

        var toolbarOptions = [
            ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],        // toggled buttons
            ['blockquote', 'code-block'],

            [{'header': 1}, {'header': 2}],               // custom button values
            [{'list': 'ordered'}, {'list': 'bullet'}],
            [{'script': 'sub'}, {'script': 'super'}],      // superscript/subscript
            [{'indent': '-1'}, {'indent': '+1'}],          // outdent/indent
            [{'direction': 'rtl'}],                         // text direction

            [{'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge']}],  // custom dropdown
            [{'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false]}],

            [{'color': []}, {'background': []}],          // dropdown with defaults from theme
            [{'font': []}],
            [{'align': []}],

            ['clean']                                         // remove formatting button
        ];
        var options = {
            debug: 'info',
            modules: {
                toolbar: toolbarOptions
            },
            placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
            readOnly: true,
            theme: 'snow'
        };
        var editor = new Quill(container, options); //this instance is not initializing

    }

})();
```

**HTML**

```
 <ng-quill-editor name="description" 
    required theme="snow"                                     
    placeholder="Enter your question here" 
    ng-model="vm.QUES" 
    class="editor">
 </ng-quill-editor>


Error:  var editor = new Quill(container, options); //this instance is not initializing
```

Comment: Make sure you have `<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.2.6/quill.js"></script>` referenced on page before ng-quill.js

Comment: yes it is there in index file, the quill editor is working fine just need to customize the toolbar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recently I have faced same issues then I gone through **ng-quill** documentation from [here](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ng-quill).

Also check issue to  here [How to configure toolbar items?](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ng-quill/issues/96)

With this component  we have two options for customizations

1. Using HTML elements add in `<ng-quill-toolbar>`
2. Set Configuration using `ngQuillConfigProvider.set()`
3. Using `modules` attribute of `ng-quill-editor` component

**1.Using HTML elements add in `<ng-quill-toolbar>`**

Please check example to [here](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ng-quill).

**2.Using ngQuillConfigProvider**

I have used following code for customization of editor

```
    .config(['ngQuillConfigProvider', function (ngQuillConfigProvider) {
          var config = {
            modules: {
              toolbar: [
                ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],        // toggled buttons
                ['blockquote', 'code-block'],

                [{ 'header': 1 }, { 'header': 2 }],               // custom button values
                [{ 'list': 'ordered' }, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
                [{ 'script': 'sub' }, { 'script': 'super' }],      // superscript/subscript
                [{ 'indent': '-1' }, { 'indent': '+1' }],          // outdent/indent
                [{ 'direction': 'rtl' }],                         // text direction

                [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],  // custom dropdown
                [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],

                [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],          // dropdown with defaults from theme
                [{ 'font': [] }],
                [{ 'align': [] }],

                ['clean'],                                         // remove formatting button

                ['link', 'image']                         // link and image, video
              ]
            },
            theme: 'snow',
            placeholder: 'Insert text here ...'
          }

          ngQuillConfigProvider.set(config);
    }]);
```

**3.Using modules attribute of ng-quill-editor component**

In controller add your editorModules

```
          $scope.editorModules = {
            toolbar: [
              ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],        // toggled buttons
              //['blockquote', 'code-block'],

              [{ 'header': 1 }, { 'header': 2 }],               // custom button values
              [{ 'list': 'ordered' }, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
              //[{ 'script': 'sub' }, { 'script': 'super' }],      // superscript/subscript
              [{ 'indent': '-1' }, { 'indent': '+1' }],          // outdent/indent
              [{ 'direction': 'rtl' }],                         // text direction

              //[{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],  // custom dropdown
              [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],

              [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],          // dropdown with defaults from theme
              //[{ 'font': [] }],
              [{ 'align': [] }],

              //['clean'],                                         // remove formatting button

              ['link', 'image']                         // link and image, video
            ]
          }
```

And add it on view like as follows

```
         <ng-quill-editor modules="editorModules" 
                           placeholder="Some text here" 
                           ng-model="message">
          </ng-quill-editor>
```

Hope this will help to someone!!

Answer (score 1):

In case you still want the editor instance to access the API or for other usages, you can 
use the `onEditorCreated` callback or any other available callbacks:
[availables callbacks/outputs](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ng-quill#callbackoutputs)

**Example:**

*In the view:*

```
<ng-quill-editor ng-model="text" on-editor-created="onEditorCreated(editor)"></ng-quill-editor>
```

*In the controller:*

```
$scope.onEditorCreated = function (editor) {
  $scope.editor = editor;
};
```